# How did this website create such a smooth scroll to view animation?

Tags: css, animation

How did this [Website](http://www.eginstill.com/project/canal-house-amsterdam/) achieve such a beautiful scroll into view effect? What i mean is the right sliding "mask" of the background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem to animate the width of a `clip` or a `wrapper` when is visible.
Probably with something like `Waypoints.js`.

https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints

With a smooth custom easing and the right timing. They also use a `parallax` on scroll which make it smoother.

Verry (verry) verry quikcly :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img ...>
</div>

// CSS

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper.visible {
  width: 500px;
  transition: width 1s ease-out;
}

img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```